# is sqlite resilient to sudden OS stop

Tags: sqlite

In case of a sudden stop (power cut for instance), is it possible to have a sqlite database corrupted?

By "corrupted" I mean that not only the latest modifications are lost, but also any other data may be wrong.

If not, how technically do they achieve it, as the database is a single file?

Comment: **That should not be possible.** The [superficial description on the website](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) explicitly mentions power failures as something that does not harm transactional integrity (thereby implying that the rest of the database is not harmed, either). A [document with more information](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) is linked from there; I assume it describes everything you are asking for in detail, though I do not feel fit right now to write a short version on my own (hence this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: Indeed your second link explains how sqlite is designed to cope with filesystems failures. However they do not talk about compressed filesystems and I wonder if their assumptions are also valid for filesystems that compress files.